# Deleting Discussion Board I Accidentally Created on Separate Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, discussion-board

I accidentally created a discussion board on my company’s sharepoint site and it seems to have been made on a separate page on its own. I need to know how to delete this discussion board?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Site Content and delete the discussion app.

Answer (score 0):

Besides from Site Contents page, you can also delete the discussion board via *LIST* tab > *List Settings* > **Delete this discussion board** under *Permissions and Management*.

Reference: [Delete a list.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/delete-a-list-2a7bca5b-b8fd-4e5b-8f4b-2ac034f3070d)